# Defining adaptive width of columns in a table

Tags: tables, width, column-width

Is there a neat way to define all column widths in a table as the **same value** and **adapted to the page size**? For example I would like the following 32 columns to have all equal width of 1/32 of the maximum page width.

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}p{0.2}}
            1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
        \captionof{table}{The solution to the backpacker problem of the first matrix obtained with analytical considerations}
```

Using this code I get a table that gets beyond the leftmost bound of the page. How can I fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: See the `tabularx` package and its `X` type columns.

Comment: Without the usage of `tabularx`: `p{\textwidth/32-2\tabcolsep}` (needs the `calc`  package instead).

Answer (score 1):

The following MWE contains two possible solutions. The first uses `X` columns from `tabularx` to automatically make the table fit into the textwidth. (The widths of `X` columns are calculated automatically). The second version manually calculates the widths for the columns with respect to the textwidth taking the length `\tabcolsep`(Distance that is added before and after the contents of each cell = half the distance between the contents of two adjacent cells) into account.

In both cases you might still need to adjust the above mentioned distance. This is done via `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}` (default is 6pt).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{32}{X}}
            1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabularx}
\captionof{table}{With X type columns from tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{*{32}{p{\textwidth/32-2\tabcolsep}}}
            1& 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{With p type columns}

\end{document}
```

[image]